# reaact-native get data from file from uri

Tags: react-native

This is a homework type question, please help as I'm new on react-native.

In react-native, I'm using `react-native-document-picker`, from the code in readme:

```
  selectFiles = () => {
    try {
      DocumentPicker.pickMultiple({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
      }).then((results) => {
        console.log(result[0].uri);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {   }
  };
```

It provides me with an URI, how can convert that into path and read data of that file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
...
RNFS.readFile(results[0].uri)
          .then((file) => {
            that.setState({code: file});
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log('err: ' + error));
```